# I place you back on the ground

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

> My infix spells an alphabet,
>   And can put things to action
>   My prefix means to criticise,
>   And undo or inaction
>
> My postfix is a sound
>   And to a plant, it is bound
>   As a verb I am found
>   I place you back on the ground

Who am I?

Hint:

> No letter is repeated in this word

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer could be:

> **Disembark**.

```
My infix spells an alphabet,
And can put things to action
```

> This could be **Em**, the letter 'M', and the prefix for putting things to action. (eg. Empower)

```
My prefix means to criticise,
And undo or inaction
```

> This could be **Dis**, as in 'diss', to criticise, as well as the prefix to remove or revert.

```
My postfix is a sound
And to a plant, it is bound
```

> This could be **Bark**, as in tree bark, and the sound.

```
As a verb I am found
I place you back on the ground
```

> Hence, **Disembark**, as in disembarking from a vehicle, or to be put back on the ground.

Comment: pipped by 3 minutes =) Nicely done.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE and congratulations on your first accepted answer!